# The Data from My Flask Server is Being Received but It Won't Append to the Text Document That I Want It to Log the Data into

Tags: python, flask, server

I'm relatively new to coding so I apologize if my post has any error or vagueness, do correct me. I am currently trying to learn Flask and I am using the Windows terminal cmd.exe.

Code written in editor:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

...

def write_to_file(data):
    with open ("database.txt",mode='a') as database:
        email = data["email"]
        subject = data["subject"]
        message = data["message"]
        file = database.write(f'\n{email}, {subject}, {message}')
        print(6)


@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        write_to_file(data)
        print(data)
        return redirect('/thankyou.html')
    else:
        return 'Something went wrong. Try again'
```

Terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2020 20:53:03] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2020 20:53:14] "[37mGET /contact.html HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
6
{'email': 'moon@gmail.com', 'subject': 'moonmoon', 'message': 'moonmoonsunmoon'}
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2020 20:54:08] "[32mPOST /submit_form HTTP/1.1[0m" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2020 20:54:08] "[37mGET /thankyou.html HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

As you can see the data is being received as email, password, and message have printed in the terminal. The number 6 has also printed so the write_to_file function seems to work, however, the function is not appending the data to my database.txt file. The text file is still blank. I have tried numerous things like restarting the server, changing the mode from 'a' to 'w' and the write_to_file function still won't write any of the collected data from the server onto the text file. Thank you for reading my post. Please do help!

Comment: Try calling open("/full/path/to/database.txt", "a") as database... still not working?

Comment: Unfortunately not. it's still not working. I forgot to mention that the python file is in the same folder as the database.txt file. But I did try writing the whole file path and using the code that you mentioned. And I did reset my server before attempting these tasks.

Comment: I find it impossible. I would advice trying to open and read the file database.txt right after you have written it, to check if it is empty at that moment. If the write failed for any reason there would be an error from python. I am convinced that something else is hapenning where we cannot see it.